Sequence and subsequence
This is from Understanding Analysis by Abbott. We have to either give an example or disprove it.

A sequence that contains subsequences converging to every point in the infinite set $\{1,1/2,1/3,1/4,1/5,...\}$, and no subsequences converging to points outside of this set.

It is easy to satisfy the first part, as we can have $a_1, a_2, a_4, a_7,...$ converge to $1$; $a_3,a_5,a_8,...$ converge to $1/2$; $a_6,a_9,a_{13}$ converge to $1/3$. What about part 2? I thought that it is possible to avoid having a subsequence converging to $0$. Since each subsequence is converging to $1/n$ and not $0$, and there is always this "gap" between any $1/n$ and $0$. I understand that we can pick a term in each of these subsequences that I mentioned earlier and it looks like it converges to 0, but I think it does not necessarily converge since each of these terms is arbitrarily close to some $1/n$ and there is this gap between $1/n$ and $0$.
Some others have posted the same question but I did not get the explanation that I wanted. It would be helpful if someone can explain part 2 to me.

You're very close, you have the right idea. Since there are subsequences converging to $\frac{1}{n}$ you can find a subsequence converging to $0$. Try to be more explicit, like this: Can you find a term $a_n$ that is at a distance $<1$ from $1$? at a distance $<\tfrac{1}{2}$ from $\tfrac{1}{2}$? etc.

"Since each subsequence is converging to 1/n and not 0, and there is always this "gap" between any 1/n and 0" Yeah..... but eventually later there will be a term that it is in another sequence that is close to $\frac 1{n+1}$ and after that there will but a term that is in another sequence that is close to $\frac 1{n+2}$ and so on  you can pick terms that get arbitririaly closer and closer to different and increasingly smaller $\frac 1n$s.  Such a subsequence gets arbitrarily close to $0$.  Can you formalize that?

Minor nitpick: you can prove or disprove a theorem statement, such as "There exists a sequence that ...".  And you can give an example of "A sequence that ...", or show that such an example cannot exist.  But it doesn't make sense to disprove an example.

If you focus on $1/n$ for only one $n$, then yes there is a "gap" between $0$ and $1/n$. So the key is to consider $n \to \infty$ (instead of a fixed $n$).

There is a subsequence converging to $1$, so there exists $i_1$ such that $|a_{i_1} - 1| < 1/2$.
For each $j=2,3,\ldots$, there is a subsequence converging to $1/j$, so there exists $i_j > i_{j-1}$ such that $|a_{i_j} - 1/j| < 1/(2j)$.
This produces a subsequence $a_{i_1}, a_{i_2}, \ldots,$ such that $|a_{i_j} - 1/j| < 1/(2j)$ for each $j$. So, $|a_{i_j}| < 3/(2j)$ for each $j$, which implies $a_{i_j} \to 0$.

For each $n$ you can find an element $a_k$ within $1/2n$ of $1/n$ with $k$ as large as you like. So you can find a subsequence  $a_{k(n)}$  with $k(n)$ increasing and $a_{k(n)}$ no larger than $3/(2n)$. That sequence converges to $0$.
